# Python: Invalid Syntax in my Else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I am starting out with Python and I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. This is an easy question for you to get a correct answer for!

Here is my code:

```
def statement(x):
    if x > 50:
        print("X is greater than 50")
    elif x < 50:
        print("X is lower than 50")
    else x == 50:
        print("X is 50")
    return
```

Very simple I know. When I try and run this, it returns an error saying invalid syntax regarding the X in my else statement:
[image: Screenshot from Python]

Could anybody please point me in the correct direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The textual and image versions of the code are different (the text contains more mistakes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else` does not take a conditional, like `if` or `elif`. If number isn't greater than 50 nor is it lesser than 50, it must be equal to 50:

```
if x > 50:
    print("X is greater than 50")
elif x < 50:
    print("X is lower than 50")
else: # no condition here!
    print("X is 50")
```

Comment: Thanks! Shall mark as correct as soon as it let's me.

Answer (score 2):

You want `elif` not `else`, or you need to remove the condition from the `else` because `else` doesn't allow for a conditional statement.

```
if ...
elif x == 50:
    print("X is 50"
```

or

```
if ...
else:
    print("X is 50")
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall mark as correct as soon as it let's me do so.